# put data from simpleDB into data gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, amazon-simpledb

I was trying to retrieve data from `Amazon` `SimpleDB` and currently it only displays data in text like `domainName`:  {attribute1, value2} {attribute1, value2}. 
How can I show the data in data grid view? My code is as follows:

```
 public static List<String> GetItemByQuery(IAmazonSimpleDB simpleDBClient, string domainName)
    {
        List<String> Results = new List<String>(); ;
        SelectResponse response = simpleDBClient.Select(new SelectRequest()
        {
            SelectExpression = "Select * from " + domainName
        });
        String res = domainName + " has: ";

        foreach (Item item in response.Items)
        {

            res = item.Name + ": ";
            foreach (Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute attribute in item.Attributes)
            {
                res += "{" + attribute.Name + ", " + attribute.Value + "}, ";
            }
            res = res.Remove(res.Length - 2);
            Results.Add(res);

        }

        return Results;
    }
```

Comment: why not fill a list<Amazon.SimpleDB.Model.Attribute> and then pull the list on grid DataSource?

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to AWS, do you mind to show me an example of applying the way you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

How you an read here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_SimpleDB_Model_SelectResult_Item.htm

your `response.Items` is

```
public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
```

so you should directly use to DataSource of your Grid, set autogenerate column to your grid to start to view the result